# Set value on form submission based on previous row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I have a script that triggers on form submission, checks the row before last row and should write a TRUE value to the 9th column of the checked row IF all three cells on its left have a TRUE value.

**My problem is that the script always writes a FALSE value, even if the 3 cells on the left are all TRUE.**

```
function onFormSubmit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var rcore = s.getSheetByName("test");
var lastrow = rcore.getLastRow();

var trgt = rcore.getRange(lastrow-1,9);

if(trgt.getValue() === ""){
  if(trgt.offset(0, -3) == "TRUE" && trgt.offset(0, -2) == "TRUE" && trgt.offset(0, -1) == "TRUE"){
    trgt.setValue("TRUE");
  } else {
  trgt.setValue("FALSE");
  }
  }
}
```

[image: Printscreen of the Sheet]

(My language is set to hungarian so that's why you see "IGAZ" for "TRUE" values and "HAMIS" for "FALSE" values)

**The 3 TRUE/FALSE values are generated by ARRAYFORMULA. Maybe that is also important**

---

SO FAR
I have tried several variations:
-tried to change the `if` to check with `offset (0, -4)` if its equal to 2 and not check anything else, but still I got FALSE values.
-I also tried to check with different `if` statements but it always gives FALSE.
-tried to check what happens if I also offset row to -1

I simply cant get a TRUE value. The last time I was able to get a TRUE value was when there was no other `if` statement, only one that checks if the cell is empty or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rubén pointed out, you need to use `.getValue()` to read the value in a range. You should also use the Boolean values `true` and `false` instead of the text strings `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"`, like this:

```js
function onFormSubmit() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rcore = ss.getSheetByName('test');
  const lastRow = rcore.getlastRow();
  const trgt = rcore.getRange(lastRow - 1, 9);
  if (trgt.getValue() === '') {
    if (trgt.offset(0, -3).getValue() === true && trgt.offset(0, -2).getValue() === true && trgt.offset(0, -1).getValue() === true) {
      trgt.setValue(true);
    } else {
      trgt.setValue(false);
    }
  }
}
```

...or more concisely:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  const rcore = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
  const trgt = rcore.getRange(rcore.getlastRow() - 1, 9);
  if (trgt.getValue() === '') {
    trgt.setValue(trgt.offset(0, -3, 1, 3).getValues().flat().every(value => value === true));
  }
}
```

Comment: Range.offset returns a Range object

Comment: Wow, thank you @doubleunary! This was the problem. Changing the "TRUES" and "FALSES" and adding getValue solved it! Also thanks Rubén for your fix here and your suggestion on my other question.